# Dropzone Laravel Form Validation error?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, laravel-5

Problem: Form post validation on images fails.
Error: Images are required

In my validation rules, i've set:

```
'images' => 'required|image',
```

In my form i've built the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">Add photos</div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <div id="myDropzone" class="dropzone">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I'm not sure how to insert the file upload form field? I am expecting the validator to throw the error. But with regards to dropzone, i'm not sure how to do it.

This is my javascript to initiate dropzone

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$('#myDropzone').dropzone({
    url: 'dashboard/add/products',
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFiles: 10,
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg',
    autoProcessQueue: false, // myDropzone.processQueue() to upload dropped files
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove image"
});
```

My Ajax request to post the form is this:

```
var form = $(this);

var formdata = new FormData(form[0]);

form.find('div.alert').remove();

e.preventDefault();

var action = $(this).attr('action');

var method = $('input[name=_method]').val() || 'POST';

$.ajax({
    type: method,
    action: action,
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;

        $.each(errors, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key + ' - ' + value);
            $('#' + key).after('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + value + '</div>');
        });

    }

});
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: not really relevant but might be useful for future reference, you are posting with laravel framework, where is your csrf token? did you put it in header?

Comment: It's a hidden input but it gets passed over.

Answer (score 1):

### 1 step - response from the server

you must send different **response** from the server to the client based on the condition of error/no error

```
// all good, no error (status code 200)
return response()->json(['message'=> $message, 'file' => $name], 200);
```

**or**

```
// Oh no, there is some error (look at the error code 400)
return response()->json(['message'=> $message, 'file' => $name], 400);
```

### 2 step - callback from dropzone

This will display the $message variable define above in the **correct place in the UI.**

```
Dropzone.options.fileUploader = {
    addRemoveLinks: true, //your config
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove file',

    init: function () {
        this.on("error", function (file, responseText) {
            var msgEl = $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message');
            msgEl.text(responseText.message);
            msgEl.show();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone sets the file field to 'file' on default.

You can change it by modifying your .dropzone() function to this:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$('#myDropzone').dropzone({
    url: 'dashboard/add/products',
    paramName: "images",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFiles: 10,
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg',
    autoProcessQueue: false, // myDropzone.processQueue() to upload dropped files
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove image"
});
```

You can browse their documementation here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration

Comment: This isn't a Dropzone specific problem, but rather a combination Laravel/Dropzone specific problem. Once the Laravel validation fails, you'll see the following if you turn on logging:

"file":["The file field is required."]

Now you have two problems:

1. Laravel will not display the error without CSS tweaking.
2. The CV will be gone, and will be have to be uploaded again.

I agree with this post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dropzone-laravel-form-validation that says front-end validation is required, unfortunately, no code sample is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count of the rejected files to detect that there is an error in your drop zone using the following code.

> dropzone variable is the drop zone object.

```
if (dropzone.getRejectedFiles().length == 0) {
//No errors
} else {
//Has errors
}
```